# How do I deal with #func! errors in cells where the function doesn't apply?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two tables that I'm joining on first name fields that sometimes have a middle initial or middle name after the first name, with a space between.  So the value could be `Jane M` or `Jane Moriarty` for the same person.

(I'm also joining on last name and DOB, but those aren't part of this problem)

Between the two lists, one usually has the whole middle name while the other usually has the middle initial.  Because of this mismatch, I need to trim the space and the characters that follow before joining.

To grab the text I want, I'm using

```
LEFT(Patients.FIRST_NAME, Instr(Patients.FIRST_NAME, ' ',) -1) as FIRST_NAME_TRIM
```

so far, so good.  However, for the cells that have neither an initial nor a middle name , e.g. `Jane`, Access returns `#func!`.  Presumably because the `Instr` can't find a space.  So when I try to join on the trimmed var, Access throws an error.  If I try it this way

```
SELECT var1, var2, var3,
    LEFT(Patients.FIRST_NAME, Instr(Patients.FIRST_NAME, ' ') -1) as FIRST_NAME_TRIM, 
    LEFT(Roster.FST_NM, Instr(Roster.FST_NM, ' ') -1) as FST_NM_TRIM
FROM Patients
INNER JOIN Roster 
    ON FIRST_NAME_TRIM = FST_NM_TRIM;
```

I get `JOIN expression not supported`

If I try it this way

```
SELECT var1, var2, var3, 
Patients_mod.FIRST_NAME_TRIM,
Roster_mod.FST_NM_TRIM
FROM 
    (
    SELECT var1, var2, var3, 
    LEFT(Patients.FIRST_NAME, Instr(Patients.FIRST_NAME, ' ') -1) as FIRST_NAME_TRIM 
    FROM Patients
    ) as Patients_mod
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT var1, var2, var3,
    LEFT(Roster.FST_NM, Instr(Roster.FST_NM, ' ',) -1) as FST_NM_TRIM
    FROM Roster
    ) as Roster_mod
ON Roster_mod.FST_NM_TRIM = Patients_mod.FIRST_NAME_TRIM;
```

I get `Syntax error in FROM clause`, and I'm not seeing a syntax error.

So I either need to prevent the `#func!` issue in the first place, or find code that ignores the cells that have `#func!`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need a tiny VBA function to get the trimmed first name. `Split()` is the best option, it works both for names with `" "` and without.

This function goes into a standard module.

```vb
Public Function GetFirstName(vName As Variant) As Variant

    If Len(vName) > 0 Then
        GetFirstName = Split(vName, " ")(0)
    Else
        GetFirstName = Null
    End If

End Function
```

Then you can join on the calculated fields:

```
SELECT Patients.First_Name, Roster.FST_NM
FROM Patients INNER JOIN Roster 
ON GetFirstName(Patients.First_Name) = GetFirstName(Roster.FST_NM);
```

(it works with `LEFT JOIN` too)

Comment: Perfect.  I was surprised to find that the module name doesn't seem to matter. Could I put a bunch of functions in one module, or is it one per? I doubt that would be a good idea, but I'm curious.

Comment: You can put as many functions as you want into one module (and it is very usual to put several into one). The module name must not be the same as a sub/function, otherwise it indeed doesn't matter. @ReidMcCamish

Comment: yeah, found that out the hard way!